# How to authenticate my user with React Material UI components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-saga

I'm using ReactJs in an application and I need to authenticate/validate my application users.

I want add some logic for user validations through redux-saga library.

When anyone enters some invalid data, validation messages should be displayed with fields.

```
import React from 'react';
import history from './history';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';


import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import { Link } from 'react-router'

import Messages from '../notifications/Messages'
import Errors from '../notifications/Errors'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";



import loginRequest from './actions/login'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));


const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Submitted!');
}

export default function Login(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    handleSubmit, // remember, Redux Form injects this into our props
    login: {
      requesting,
      successful,
      messages,
      errors,
    },
  } = props

  // Remember, Redux Form passes the form values to our handler
  // In this case it will be an object with `email` and `password`
  // submit = (values) => {
  //   this.props.loginRequest(values)
  // }
// Pass the correct proptypes in for validation
  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        {/* noValidate */}
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)} >
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth            
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth           
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>             
        </form>
      </div>      
    </Container>
  );
}


Login.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  loginRequest: PropTypes.func,
  login: PropTypes.shape({
    requesting: PropTypes.bool,
    successful: PropTypes.bool,
    messages: PropTypes.array,
    errors: PropTypes.array,
  }),
};
```

I've grabbed the example code for authentication from here:

https://github.com/jcolemorrison/redux-sagas-authentication-app/blob/login/src/login/index.js

```
    Application built with
    {
      "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
 "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
    }
```

The problem i face is getting errors while converting  ES6 component class to material Ui pure react component (based on function approach). Both have many variances.

Currently i am getting an error on following conversion but there is a possibility for more errors during conversion.

```
 submit = (values) => {
     this.props.loginRequest(values)
   }
```

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not find the recommended way to solve the the issue.

I am facing tow major problems

1). Converting Material UI component (based on functional approach) to ES6 class based component.

2). If there is not a simple way for point#1 then I want to convert (provided code in example) ES6 class based component to Pure react component (based on functional approach)

Thank you

Comment: is `loginRequest` a redux action?

Comment: Yes.please see here https://github.com/jcolemorrison/redux-sagas-authentication-app/blob/login/src/login/actions.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functional components, there are no class properties, hence you can't use `this`.

In addition, `loginRequest` seems to be a redux action. If you want to access it within your component as part of its props, you will need to convert it into a connected component using `connect()`, and use `mapDispatchToProps`. Alternatively, you can use the `useDispatch` hook to dispatch redux actions.

This is one way the submit method should be written (with the `useDispatch` hook):

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const submit = (values) => {
  dispatch(loginRequest(values));
};
```

And on your form, you will need to bind the `submit` method to the `onSubmit` event

```
    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submit} >
```

Comment: Than you wentjun. What other conversions can be an issue ? I usually face too much usage of ES6 bases class components. Should i go for Material UI (function based) components to class based components or  class based components to function based components ?

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't matter if you are using class/function based, as they are opinionated. But moving forward, it is recommended to stick to function components as they tend to be preferred these days.